# Add json Elements and values to Multiple json objects

Tags: javascript, json

I want combine a JSON object to an ARRAY.
I would like retrieve data from keys finded on var product, and combine score finded to a new variable ( combined results )

combinedresults is what I need. I absolutely don't know how to do this

```js
var product = {
    "presentation": 3,
    "imgmax": http://test.com/img.jpg,
    "puissance": 5,
    "efficacite": 4,
    "description": "This product is awesome but i need to combine JSON results"
}

var array = [
  {
  "caracname": "presentation",
  "name": "Présentation"
  },
  {
  "caracname": "efficacite",
  "name": "Efficacité"
  },
  {
  "caracnam": "puissance",
  "name": "Puissance"
  }
]




var combinedresults = [
    {
    "caracname": "presentation",
    "name": "Présentation",
    "score": 3
    },
    {
    "caracname": "efficacite",
    "name": "Efficacité",
    "score": 4
    },
    {
    "caracnam": "puissance",
    "name": "Puissance",
    "score": 5
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate through each item of the array, if the product object contains a key that matches the current items caracname, add it's value as a score.

See below:

```js
var product = {
    "presentation": 3,
    "imgmax": "http://test.com/img.jpg",
    "puissance": 5,
    "efficacite": 4,
    "description": "This product is awesome but i need to combine JSON results"
}

var array = [
  {
  "caracname": "presentation",
  "name": "Présentation"
  },
  {
  "caracname": "efficacite",
  "name": "Efficacité"
  },
  {
  "caracname": "puissance",
  "name": "Puissance"
  }
]

array.forEach(function(item) {

  if (product[item.caracname]) {
    item.score = product[item.caracname];
  }
  
});

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply map over your current array, extending every object with the score attribute.

```
array.map(obj => ({...obj, score: product[obj.caracname]}));
```

If you are not familiar, consider having a look at the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator);